# 80's (or earlier) sci-fi book about a young adult fighting enemy spaceships in a space suit with long tentacles

Tags: story-identification, books, space-combat

I read this book in the late 80's.  I know it's not the *Ender's Game* series.

From what I remember, the book is about a young adult/teenager who is used to fight against enemy spaceships. They have him wear a 'space suit' that has these long tails/tentacles that are used for offense.

I also remember that part of the story is about training him on how to interface and use the suit.

Comment: Could this be one of Saberhagen's Berserker stories?  There was one about a young man bred/trained to be installed in a multipurpose/ multifunction weapons suit that could manifest grasping or cutting fields.  He essentially lived symbiotically inside this suit for years.  At one point he travelled to another star at sub-light speed, but fast enough to experience extreme blue-shift (which was described, but the character did not understand).

Comment: This description reminded me of the Berserker stories also.